# Determine returned columns from stored procedure data type SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can execute stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, but I do not have rights to see it`s definition.

How can I determine data type for each returned column?

I can see input parameter types, but not types for returned rows.

Comment: Can you specify more what you want to achieve? Give an example of how you call the stored procedure, and what happens, and if you like to use a programming language to solve this problem - if it can be done, what kind of programming language do you prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe get your question wrong, but I will try to answer this, maybe it is not a solution but at least a try...

You could use a programming language and call the stored procedure, e.g. Java.
And the check the returns by using `ResultSetMetaData`.

```
 ResultSet rs = ...
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 String columnLabel = rsmd.getColumnLabel(1);
 String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
 int columnType = rsmd.getColumnType(1);
 String columnTypeName = getColumnTypeName(1);

 etc
```

This is of course as I assume that you don't have any rights to check the stored procedure in any way (no access to system tables, etc. But only access you have is that you can run the SP).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: This was the long way as this procedure took many required parameters :(

Answer (score -1):

This table "sys.parameters" would provide you all the details regarding the SP.

Thanks !

Comment: Where can I find this table?

Comment: You can view this in your present DB. where the SP is created.

Comment: That catalog **view** provides insight into the **parameters** the stored procedure expects - **NOT** into what data that stored procedure returns!